# Understanding addressing and size in memory map

Tags: arm, memory, cortex-m

TM4C123 has **256 kiBytes** of flash ROM as shown in the memory map. The range of memory addresses for the ROM is 0x0000.0000 to 0x0003.FFFF (a 32bit address), totaled to 3x16x16x16x16 = 196,608 number of addresses. The memory is byte addressable so that block of memory addresses adds up to **196,608 bytes** instead. Why does the manufacturer claim it has 256 kiB and not 196kB ROM memory size?

Even if the range of addresses can't sum up to an exact 256k, wouldn't 0x0000.0000 - 0.0004.FFFF (4x16x16x16x16 = 262k) give a size closer to 256k than 0x0003.FFFF's 196k?

[image: memory map]

Comment: It starts at 0, so 4 X 16 x ... not 3 x. See also "fencepost error"

Comment: It has 00000000 up to 0000FFFF, then it has 00010000 up to 0001FFFF, then it has 00020000 up to 0002FFFF, then it has 00030000 up to 0003FFFF. 4 lots of 0000 up to FFFF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an off by one error in your calculations and also kilobyte is not 1000 bytes but 1024. The device really has 256 kilobytes of memory. 2^18 is 262144 bytes and 262144 / 1024 is exactly 256 kilobytes. A kilobyte is 2^10 = 1024 bytes.

Comment: Well, according to international engineering standards, 2^10 bytes is a kibibyte and not a kilobyte. You can say I'm being pedantic, but flash drive manufacturers lost a lot of money in lawsuits over the matter.